# Use string as primary key to store words

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I am planning to create one huge table to store all words that could possibly exist for personal experimentation (whether part of the official dictionary, urban or else).

Does it make sense to use the word itself as a primary key?
It is 100% certain that words MUST be unique, moreover they will not change.

The purpose in the end is to also use this PK as FK in related tables to get more information on these words.

I am not too familiar with table scaling, so I wonder if I can get into trouble:

- Performance wise
- If the table becomes too large and has to be partitioned (?)
- If I want to move the database to sqlite to use as embedded data store

Tagging this question with postgres (my current db), but may migrate to sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be surprised if there were enough words that you needed to partition the table.  Of course if your "words" are really genetic sequences or something, I might be off there.

In any case, one of the primary purposes of a `primary key` is to support foreign key relationships.  So, if there is any possibility that  another table might refer to this table, then you want to take that into account.

Integer foreign keys are generally preferable, because they are a fixed length -- and that is a little more efficient for indexes.  In addition, four-byte integers are probably smaller than  the average word length, so they save on storage of the foreign key as well.

That would be balanced against an additional 4 bytes in the `words` table itself.  On balance, I usually add synthetic primary keys.

Comment: Sorrgate keys it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another Idea:

Make 2 columns

- Column 1: Initial Letter
- Column 2: The Word

[if word is APPLE :::: Column1-->A :::: Column2-->Apple]

Benefits:

- you can query faster for tasks like 'word count from a letter' (like, no. of words from A)
- could give you simple rules for making shards (like all words with column1 as 'A', can be assigned to a particular dedicated shard)

Comment: Sure, but initial letter isn't a primary key